# How to let user provide size of items in carousel?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to create carousel like this which shows multiple items:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zuufc.png)

I have one problem though. I want the let the user decide
how she wants to draw each item, for this I will give her `renderItem` function as a prop of the component.

Now comes my question: When user clicks arrows on carousel I want it to move to next item exactly, so I need to know the width of the item so I can say move the parent div with that many pixels say on the right or left.

How do I know the width of the item when user decides how to render each item herself, she may even draw different items differently (although that is not common with carousels)?

**Shall I ask user to fill `itemWidth` prop? This would make implementation easier but I wonder maybe there is better approach?**

I am a bit lost and some guidance appreciated.

Comment: More information like your source code will be required to help solve this question effectively.

Comment: @FinHARRIS Why do you need source code? If something is not clear ask me, I don't have source code because I didn't decide how to approach this problem

Comment: I see. With the information provided, I do not understand what you are asking. What will the renderItem method do?

Comment: @FinHARRIS Check carousels they often have it: `renderItem` is function which user passes as prop to the component and which decides how each carousel item is drawn.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the width of any HTML element by using the property "offsetWidth".

In react you can use "refs" or document.getElementById to point to exact element.
`document.getElementById("your_id").offsetWidth`